# Custom taxonomy meta fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, template-hierarchy

I'm trying to make an anime site like myanimelist.net but in spanish with links of the episodes at the bottom. I created a post type called anime, and some custom taxonomies associated with it: series, movies, ovas, specials, live action, producers, themes, genres, and characters. I used advanced custom fields to assign meta fields to the taxonomies with fields like image, synopsis, type, alternative title, episodes, status, aired, producers, genre, themes, duration and rating.

Here is what i want to do: Make one template for all the terms from series that displays the fields that i assigned to each one. So people could visit the term and see the information about the series. Example www.example.com/series/one-piece and it shows the information about that specific series. At the bottom they could see the link to each episode(post) assign to that term.

I would like someone to help me make that template if its possible or tell me if I'm doing it right using taxonomies with metafields if its not the best way to do what i want to accomplished, point me in the right direction. I been trying to learn how to code php so i know a little, had read about 200 pages of a couple php book while at work but i understand some of the code if a see it.

I would really appreciated the help. Thanks a lot in advanced!

PD: I can't use Organize Series plugin as that would be only for the series taxonomy and i need it for movies, ovas, specials, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with the coding part that much, you can always take a look on [WCK](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/) plugin, that allows you to create custom taxonomies, and allow your users to see the information displayed as you want.